# Connect field with Taxonomy Term

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms

I have taxonomy `Brand` and different fields like `RAM`, `Monitor`, 'CPU' under content-type `Hardware`.

While adding a new Hardware how can I add RAM, CPU or other fields with Brands?
e.g.

```
RAM = 16 GB, Brand = Corsair
Monitor = 24", Brand = Dell
...
```

I can allow `Brand` taxonomy to unlimited and can add multiple, but is that possible to connect with particular fields? Or is there any better approach?

#### Update:

Other solution I was thinking was to add multiple `Brand` fields like `RAM Brand`, `Monitor Brand` etc. Is this the only approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me make sure I understand what you are asking:

**Brand** is a taxonomy vocabulary.

**Hardware** is a node content type.

**Hardware** has fields:

- RAM
- CPU

Now, the question is, how do you specify different brands for RAM and CPU?

There are a couple ways to do this.

**Create multiple Brand taxonomy term reference fields.**

In this approach, you will add a taxonomy term reference field for each field on hardware that you want to set a brand for.

For example:

- RAM
- RAM brand (taxonomy term reference field)
- CPU
- CPU brand (taxonomy term reference field)

However, this is a bad approach if many pieces of hardware have RAM with the same capacity and brand (for example, you have 10 pieces of hardware with Corsair 32 GB).

**The Drupal way: Create more content types**

The most "Drupal" way to do this is to create content types for each "thing" you are trying to model and then combine them.

So, you would create:

- RAM content type with fields **capacity** and **brand** ("brand" taxonomy term entity reference)
- CPU content type with fields **speed** and **brand** ("brand" taxonomy term entity reference)
- Hardware content type with fields **RAM** ("RAM" node entity reference) and **CPU** ("CPU" node entity reference)

This is the most flexible approach, although it takes a little more time to set up.

Comment: Thanks for the descriptive answer, I like both approach. For first example you said it's bad approach for many hardware, but I have other fields like serial number, manufacturer etc. So that should be fine right?

Comment: @shyammakwana.me Yes, fields like serial number and hardware manufacturer are fine.  The basic idea is that "each thing/object should have its own content type, and the fields for the properties of that thing/object should be on the relevant content type".  So, it's fine to have a "HW serial number" on hardware, but you would generally not want "HW serial number" + "RAM serial number" on hardware ("RAM serial number" should be with RAM).

Comment: I see what you're saying. Segregating to the last thing/object is good approach. I thought to put RAM's serial number in "HW Serial Number" and RAM's brand in "RAM Brand" and likewise for Keyboard. But thanks.